# Pass Email Id as parameter in WCF restful service

Tags: wcf, web-services

Suppose I have a web service which accept email id and password as parameter in url . I have to authenticate user by email id and password.    `using System;using System.Collections.Generic;using System.Linq;using System.Runtime.Serialization;using System.ServiceModel;using System.Text;using System.ServiceModel.Web;namespace WebApp.Services{[ServiceContract]public interface IService  {        [WebInvoke(Method = "GET",        UriTemplate = "/authenticate/{emailId}/{password}",        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,        RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]        [OperationContract]        Boolean Authenticate(string emailId, string password);    }}`

we call web service like it :

http://localhost:14176/Services/Service.svc/Authenticate/sushant.bhatnagar@greatdevelopers.com/123

because email contain '.' which is not encoded by the web browser , so web service function is not called .

There is any solution to pass email id in url other than query string .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If You could use POST:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IMyService
{
     [OperationContract]
     bool Authenticate(EmailCredential request);
}

[DataContract]
public class EmailCredential 
{
     [DataMember]
     public string EmailId {get; set;}

     [DataMember]
     public string Password {get; set;}
}
```

and call service using WebClient or WebHttpRequest with that xml (i don't know now how json looks like for this so xml)

```
    <EmailCredential >
        <EmailId >sushant.bhatnagar@greatdevelopers.com</EmailId >
        <Password >123</Password >
    </EmailCredential >
```

Comment: oh it is another way for doing it , but there is any alternative way for it with GET request .

Comment: Unfortunately every GET request will be refused cause problem u mention:/ So I see that only solution is POST.

Comment: There is a option if you send email id as base 64 encoded and in service function decoded it .